# How i recognize a unique sound in a noisy environment?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, fft, waveform, audio-processing

I am developing app to detect the inability of elderly people  to unlock their rooms using IC cards in their daycare center.
 This room doors has an electronic circuit that emits  beep sounds d to signal the user failure in  unlock  the room. My goal is to detect this beep signal.
I have searched a lot and found some possibilities:

1. To clip the beep sound  and use as a template signal and compare it with test signal (the complete human door interaction audio clip) using convolution, matched filters, DTW or what so ever to measure their  similarity. What do u recommend and how to implement it.
2. To analyze the FFT of beep sound to see if it has a frequency band different that of the background noise. I do not understand how to do it exactly?
3. To check whether the beep sound form a peak at certain frequency spectrum  that is absent in the background noise. If so, Implement a freclipped the beep sound and got the  spectrogram as shown in the figure [spectrogram of beep sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7NdD.png). but i cannot interpret it? could u give me  a detailed explanation of the spectrogram.

3.What is your recommendation? If you have other efficient method for beep detection, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to calculate the full spectrum. If you know the frequency of the beep, you can just do a single point DFT and continuously check the level at that frequency. If you detect a rising and falling edge within a given interval it must be the beep sound.

You might want to have a look at the [Goertzel Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm). It is an algorithm for continuous single point DFT calculation.

Comment: How to know the frequency of beep sound?

Comment: I am no Audacity expert, but looking at your spectrogram I would say it is between 3.05 and 3.10 kHz

Comment: Btw. here is the link to the documentation of the spectrogram view of Audacity: http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/spectrogram_view.html